# How to setup Packet Tunnel Provider with device-internal VPN

Tags: ios, vpn, networkextension

I'm trying to build an iOS app that lists all requests that are made from the device, like `Charles Proxy` does. Much like Charles, my idea has been to create a `Packet Tunnel Provider` and have it setup a local VPN connection without an external VPN server. The traffic would then be internally routed to the packet tunnel, without requiring an external VPN server.

Since `Charles Proxy` does so, I know that it is technically possible, but I can't find any information about how to setup a tunnel with an internal VPN connection, instead of using a "real" external VPN server. The only resource people refers to is the `SimpleTunnel` Apple sample project, which is a couple years old and written in Swift 3.

I have downloaded the `SimpleTunnel` sample code project, created the correct entitlements and can now run the project and create a VPN configuration that gets listed under Settings, but I just can't connect the VPN tunnel. I have tried changing the server address to `127.1.0.0` and to use `IKEv2`, but without success. I have also downloaded the source code at https://github.com/lxdcn/NEPacketTunnelVPNDemo but didn't get it to work either.

Does anyone know how to setup an internal VPN server with `NetworkExtensions` and have the tunnel use that connection?

Comment: That's what this master thesis explains
https://nsg.ee.ethz.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/theses/MA-2016-47.pdf

Comment: [NEPacketTunnelVPNDemo](https://github.com/lxdcn/NEPacketTunnelVPNDemo) this one will work with external VPN server basically you will have to run [Simple VPN Demo Server Code](https://github.com/lxdcn/simple-vpn-demo) on linux machine and copy over the IP address of linux machine to viewcontroller.swift  then you can connect but this project is not about creating a VPN connection without any external VPN server

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H Have you done the internal VPN server with NetworkExtension?

Comment: @Vladislav - You mean [NEPacketTunnelVPNDemo](https://github.com/lxdcn/NEPacketTunnelVPNDemo).I wasn't aware it has internal VPN server.

Comment: Did you achieve success in your research, Daniel? I'm currently looking for the same solution and stuck on the same challenge.

Comment: Have you made any progress here?

Comment: let setting = NEPacketTunnelNetworkSettings(tunnelRemoteAddress:vpnServer ) , then config setting, after this ,provier call setTunnelNetworkSettings.if no params error ,VPN connected. read/write packets or startup http server, setup  NEProxyServer, http request will connect local http server.

Comment: I haven't worked with this anymore.

Comment: @OdNairy any update from your side?

Comment: @wheresmycookie any luck ?

Comment: @Omarj Unfortunately, no.

Comment: @Ricardo how can I reach those guys ? I have some questions regarding there solution.
For example what happened to the packet if u decided to not write it to your session? it will be dropped and the user gets bad access or something like that or it will goes back to normal network layers ? without VPN tunnel